# Tab Bar iOS - Filter Core Data Only

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have a concept question, that i am having real issues with.

I have a Master/Detail application that i would like to add a Tab Bar to, but only to filter core data, basically just changing the predicate for the Fetch Request.

Now, i could add a Tab Bar, add my Navigation Controller to it, modify some code and make it work. But i would then need to create multiple screens/fetch controllers e.t.c for each view i wish to display. Whereas what i would like to do is just re-filter the results on a change in the Tab Bar.

Please excuse me if this is a stupid question, i am coming from an OSX background, and on that it is very straightforward!

Thanks in Advance!

Gareth

Answer (score 0):

`UITabBar` is a type of view, so you can add it as a subview of one of your existing views and set yourself as the delegate. Then you can update your fetch request in the `tabBar:didSelectItem:` method. You don't need to use `UITabBarController`.

Comment: Hmm, but how do i add the UITabBar, it doesn't seem to like being added to the table view, as it just hugs the bottom of the table cell. If i add a new view to the same screen, and attach it to that, the tableview just appears over the top of it. I guess i need to tell the tableview to draw shorter?

Comment: You want to have a view to contain everything and the table view and tab bar view as subviews of that.

Comment: Ok, will give it a go, i think i tried this before and the table view point blank refused to be a sub-view of the blank view, but i'll give it another go. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems easiest to just create multiple instances of your view, each with an appropriate filter property set and then add all of those instances to your Tabbar controller array.